# Showing that with Dirichlet boundary values, the operator $\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}$ is Hermitian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, boundary-conditions

That is, that $\langle f, \frac{\partial^4g}{\partial x^4}\rangle = \langle \frac{\partial^4f}{\partial x^4},g \rangle$.

I've been trying working by definition (for the first step), and using integration by parts for the second step:

$$\langle f , \frac{\partial^4g}{\partial x^4} \rangle = \int f^*\frac{\partial^4g}{\partial x^4}dx=f^*\frac{\partial^3g}{\partial x^3}| - \int{\frac{\partial f^*}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^3g}{\partial x^3} }dx = - \int{\frac{\partial f^*}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^3g}{\partial x^3} }dx$$
the last step can be explained with dirichlet boundary values, as in the boundaries, f is equal to 0.

now, as i continue with the integration by parts:

$$- \int{\frac{\partial f^*}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^3g}{\partial x^3} }dx = -\frac{\partial f^*}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}| + \int\frac{\partial^2 f^*}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}dx$$
The expression does not go to $0$. and it goes like this as i continue.
How can I prove it?

Comment: Where is the physics in this? This would probably be a better fit for maths SE.

Comment: The 4th derivative is the momentul to the power of 4, the second term in the series expansion needed in the Klein-Gordon equation's non-relativistic limit. So symmetry or self-adjointness of this diff.operator is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirichlet is not enough for your operator to be self-adjoint, or even Hermitian.

Indeed, be careful!  "Hermitian" is probably not what you want. There is a distinction between mere hermiticity and self-adjointness.  It is the latter condition that is needed for an operator to have a complete set of eigenvalues and hence be a QM observable.

There is a nice discussion of your operator  [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907069). In particlular  a paradoxical property is shown in example 7 on page 8, and the resolution, that   he operator $H =d^4/dx^4$ on the interval $[-a,a]$ is self-adjoint in the domain
$$
{\mathcal D}[H] =\{\psi, \psi^{''''} \in L^2[-a,a], \hbox{ and } \psi(\pm a)= \psi''(\pm a)=0\},
$$
is discussed around page 43 and  equation A.10 of that paper.